# How to use filters and skiptoken effectively while getting sign-in logs using Graph API? - Unsupported Query

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

I have used below `graph api` to fetch the users and their `sign in` activities

```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,mail, displayName,signInActivity
```

This returned me the `response` in following format

```
 {
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(id,mail,displayName,signInActivity)",
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id%2cmail%2c+displayName%2csignInActivity&$skiptoken=<some random token>",
"value": [
    {
        "mail": "sample-01@gmail.com",
        "displayName": "Sample 01 User",
        "id": "Xa0eXXdX-xaX0-XXXX-1f09-efcXXcXXaXcX",
        "signInActivity": {
            "lastSignInDateTime": "2021-08-03T06:32:39Z",
            "lastSignInRequestId": "Xa0eXXdX-xaX0-XXXX-1f09-efcXXcXXaXcX",
            "lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime": "2021-08-03T06:30:43Z",
            "lastNonInteractiveSignInRequestId": "85454bb0-8550-4eee-82f5-0b31a50ad700"
        }
    },
    {
        "mail": "sample-02@gmail.com",
        "displayName": "Sample 02 User",
        "id": "y1ed00yY-y004-YYf1-YYc6-YYYceYYYYb2a"
    },
```

**Question number#01**

Why I am not able to see all the user's sign in activity! `Azure Portal` shows more sign in activities than graph API returned.

**Question number#02**

What does `@odata.nextLink` refers to? Does it mean my next set of data available using new URL?

**Question number#03**

How do I get only a response which has `signInActivity` details. In the above example `Sample 02 User` does not have `signInActivity`.  I do not want his details in the response.

Some guidance is appreciated!

**Updated Question**

Tried below query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,mail,displayName,signInActivity&$filter=signInActivity ne null
```

but returns error as shown below

```
   {
"error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "Unsupported Query.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2022-05-25T07:07:53",
        "request-id": "11d11210-b31e-11da-aa9e-11c6e156b14d",
        "client-request-id": "24d24210-b31e-45da-aa1e-56c6e156b14d"
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For some endpoints Graph API doesn't return all records but it returns multiple pages of data either due to server-side paging or due to the use of the `$top` query parameter to specifically limit the page size in a request.

When more than one query request is required to retrieve all the results, Graph API returns an `@odata.nextLink` property in the response that contains a URL to the next page of results.

If you want filter out users without `signInActivity` you can use `$filter` clause and return only users where `signInActivity` is not equal `null`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,mail,displayName,signInActivity&$filter=signInActivity ne null
```

Resources:

- [Paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging)
- [User properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties)

Comment: tried but It returns error - "message": "Unsupported Query.",

Comment: @kudlatiger It's working for me. I've tested the query in Graph Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer I will check it

Comment: I have tried using Postman tool and not working

Comment: Graph explorer does not have the capabilities to change the tenant/directory id as my users are in a different tenant.  Hence I am using postman. but API shall work the same everywhere.